# Unit Test these methods?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Hi I was wondering how I could unit test the methods below:

```
 public float calcNP()
    {

        int rowcount = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;

        int[] colB = new int[rowcount];
        float[] NP = new float[rowcount];
        float avgNP = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < rowcount; i++)
        {
            colB[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);


        }

        float min = colB.Min();
        float max = colB.Max();
        float a = 1, b = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < rowcount; i++)
        {
            NP[i] = (a + (colB[i] - min) * (b - a)) / (max - min);
            avgNP = NP[i] + avgNP;



        }

        avgNP = (avgNP / rowcount) * 100;
        return avgNP;
    }
```

and also the following

```
  public float calcIFact()
    {

        float ftp = calcFTP();
        float NP = calcNP();
        float IntFact = NP / ftp;

        return IntFact;


    }
```

and this

```
public float calcFTP()
    {

        float ftp = 0;

        if (chkFTP.Checked == true)
        {
            //  ftp =(float)Convert.ToDouble(txtFTP.Text)/100;
            ftp = (float)Convert.ToDouble(txtFTP.Text);

        }

        if (chkFTP.Checked == false)
        {
            int rowcount = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;

            int[] colB = new int[rowcount];


            for (int i = 0; i < rowcount; i++)
            {
                colB[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);


            }
            //  ftp = colB.Max() / 100;

            ftp = colB.Max();
        }
```

If someone could give me some examples that would be great.

Basically just need some simple tests for the calculations

Comment: You'll have a hard time unit testing methods that depend on the values in a data grid.  Move the calculation logic into separate methods that take the numbers as input and don't reference the data grid, then unit test those methods.

Comment: Okay, not got much time to fiddle round with it just need to create some tests for the project as a whole. How hard would it be to unit test some chart functions?

Comment: @user2913240 Writing good unit tests requires investing time and refactoring code to support good testing practices. BJ Myers told you a good way to approach the refactoring. Your method as currently written relies on state from outside the scope of the method you want to test. This makes it hard to test. Unit testing is all about validating that for a specific set of inputs, you receive back a specific set of outputs.

Comment: Trying to test code that depends on UI elements is going to take a lot longer than just refactoring the logic into separate methods and testing those.

Comment: Based on comment conventional answer (refactor to allow testing) is not acceptable. Please clarify what is acceptable so it can be answered, otherwise will likely be closed as "unclear" or "too broad".

Comment: I was going to ask the same thing, refactor is not really making it clear or helping me..

Comment: What's not clear about the statement "Move the calculation logic into separate methods that take the numbers as input and don't reference the data grid, then unit test those methods"?

Comment: @user2913240, what's the point of asking a question if you're not willing to accept guidance? In it's current state, your code is *not* testable.

Comment: I am willing to accept guidance, was just unaware of what was meant by it.

Answer (score 2):

We are telling you to do this:

```
// New method, not depending on a gridview. Testable.
public float calcNP_pure(int[] colB)
{
    float[] NP = new float[colB.Length];
    float avgNP = 0;

    float min = colB.Min();
    float max = colB.Max();
    float a = 1, b = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < rowcount; i++)
    {
        NP[i] = (a + (colB[i] - min) * (b - a)) / (max - min);
        avgNP = NP[i] + avgNP;
    }

    avgNP = (avgNP / rowcount) * 100;
    return avgNP;
}

// Not testable
public float calcNP()
{
    int rowcount = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
    int[] colB = new int[rowcount];
    for (int i = 0; i < rowcount; i++)
    {
        colB[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
    }
    return calcNP_pure(colB);
}
```

This new method should also go into a new class and not sit on a form or some other UI-element. The best practice is to program against interfaces and to inject required dependencies into the objects:

```
public interface INpCalculator
{
    float CalcNP(int[] values);
}

public class NpCalculator : INpCalculator
{
    public float CalcNP(int[] values)
    {
        ...
        return ...;
    }
}   

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private INpCalculator _npCalculator;

    public Form1(INpCalculator npCalculator)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _npCalculator = npCalculator;
    }

    private float CalcNP()
    {
        int[] colB = dataGridView1.Rows
            .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .Select(row => row.Cells[5].Value)
            .ToArray();
        return _npCalculator.CalcNP(colB);
    }
}
```

Now the calculator is testable without the need to open any form:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestNpCalculator()
{
    // Arrange
    var sut = new NpCalculator();
    var values = new int[] { 12, 7, 15, 3 };

    // Act
    float result = sut.CalcNP(values);


    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(123.456f, result);
}
```

Btw: `sut` stands for "system under test".

Answer (score 0):

In current state of the method, your unit tests are going to require manually create datagrid object and populate values as per your testing scenario. As suggested by Daniel, your method  "public float calcNP()" should not use data grid, instead of that you can pass an array of integers to the method (pass only values which you are going to use in calculation)